# Add Service Reference: Ordering of Serialization Fields

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a C# web service client in Visual Studio 2008 with a Java web service endpoint. I have no control over the endpoint and the SOAP messages that it sends back.

I created an auto-generated proxy client from the web service WSDL using the "Add Service Reference" option in Visual Studio. When I send my request I get a valid SOAP message back, which contains something like this:

```
<java:a_field xmlns:java="java:com.whatever">Value1</java:a_field>
<java:different_field xmlns:java="java:com.whatever">Value2</java:different_field>
```

However, it does not actually parse those two values, and all of the values after that are null. After debugging, I found that this code in the auto-generated Reference.cs was the problem:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=30)]
public string different_field {
    get {
        return this.different_fieldField;
    }
    set {
        this.different_fieldField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("different_field");
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=31)]
public string a_field {
    get {
        return this.a_fieldField;
    }
    set {
        this.a_fieldField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("a_field");
    }
}
```

These two fields are out of order, so it doesn't serialize them properly, and the rest of the fields are not serialized at all. The WSDL itself declares the fields in the same order that the proxy class is expecting them in, it's just the actual response that changes the order. I can work around this by manually swapping the two Order= values, but that would be a huge pain to maintain given that the WSDLs change frequently and there are 100s of fields that need to be checked for this kind of error. Is there any better way for me to be able to ignore this ordering mismatch and still use the auto-generated web service proxy?

Comment: The order matters, assuming these two elements are declared inside of an `<xs:sequence>` in the WSDL. If they service sends them in the wrong order, then the service is _broken_. They may not even be aware of this. Please tell them so they can fix it.

Comment: Yes they are declared in a <xs:sequence>. I agree that the service itself seems to be the root cause of this problem, but as I said I cannot force the creators of this web service to make any changes. It works fine for other clients even with this bug, including the client I had made in Visual Studio 2005 using the Web Reference functionality.

Comment: I didn't suggest forcing them to make a change. I suggested that you make them aware of the difference between their WSDL and their messages. They may not be aware of it, and may even be grateful to you for informing them.

Comment: I will make the team responsible for it aware of the bug and based on previous experience it may or may not ever get fixed. For the purposes of answering the question assume that it is not fixed and I need some sort of long-term workaround.

Comment: As an update this issue was finally resolved over two years after it appeared because the team responsible for maintaining the web service was forced to move to a different Java application framework for unrelated reasons.

Comment: Great to know it was solved, Chris. Can you tell us what the old and new frameworks are and what versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having dealt with something similar, and knowing that it's a giant pain, I would suggest creating your own "fake" WSDL that reflects what is actually returned from the web service instead of what is specified.  The issue appears to relate more to an inaccurate XSD that is part of the WSDL.  It seems that some of the Java web service frameworks do not follow the order (or other specifications) strictly by default, and your third-party web service provider may not have the knowledge, resources, or motivation to fix the problem.

It is better still, as a matter of best practice, not to import the WSDL at all as a service reference, instead creating the interfaces and service proxies by hand and the configuration either manually or with the WCF Service Configuration Editor.  There are a number of resources on how to do this -- Google is your friend.

Comment: In my opinion the only redeeming quality of SOAP for web services is that it allows auto-generation of parsing code, writing parsing code for hundreds of fields would be significantly more work than dealing with these ordering issues. The hand-modified WSDL file involves slightly less work than hand-modifying the code, and is what I ended up doing before this answer was posted.